# optimization with inequality and bound constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, maximization

I would like to conduct an optimization with inequality and bound constraints:

To maximize `f= SEA (a,b,c,d)`

with constraints

```
Pmax (a,b,c,d)<=145
0 <= a <= 10
80 <= b <= 240
0.5<= c <= 1.5
0 <= d <=0.534
```

Based on literatures, fmincon is an appropriate option. However, in Minitab help, the examples are separated between inequality and bound constraints. How can i write this problem in matlab using both types of constraints?

Comment: can you try to explain in less technical language or give a real world example of the problem ?